# Python named argument scope is confusing, when it has a default list value

Tags: python

I am confused by the scope of the names argument used in following example

```
def disp( p1, list=[] ):
    list.append( p1 )
    return list 

list1 = disp( 10 )
list2 = disp( 123 )
list3 = disp( 'a' )

print ( list1 )
print ( list2 )
print ( list3 )
```

Output is

```
[10, 123, 'a']
[10, 123, 'a']
[10, 123, 'a']
```

How can we explain the scope of the variable list, which is the named argument in the function definition?
Instead of a list, if it's something else, say integer, its works differently.

```
def disp2( p1, myVal = 0 ):
    myVal += myVal + p1 
    return myVal 

v1 = disp2(9)
v2 = disp2(7)
v3 = disp2(77)

print ( v1, v2, v3 )
```

Ideas? I want to understand the details behind the first example (its easy to avoid it, by changing the code ).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23029727/why-do-list-operations-in-python-operate-outside-of-the-function-scope

Answer (score 1):

In Python, some types are immutable (`str`, `int`, etc.) while others are mutable (`list`, `dict`, `tuple`, etc).

Your code behaves like that because you are setting the default argument as **mutable** type (`list=[]`), which in returns results in the **same object** but with **different (updated) values (content)**.

[This article](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html) might be a good reading to understand this behaviour and how to potentially solve it.

Answer (score 0):

> Python’s default arguments are **evaluated once when the function is
> defined, not each time the function is called**. This means that if you use a mutable default argument and
> mutate it, you will and have **mutated that object for all future calls**
> to the function as well.

https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments

Answer (score 0):

Well the default values get assigned once only,

And your not copying the list you just added another key *variable* to reach it so all of them are the same list in this case

so do this

```
def disp( p1, list = None ):
    if list is None: # None is nothing
        list = [] 
    list.append( p1 )
    return list 

# here you don't need to copy since there different lists
# unlike then
list1 = disp( 10 )
list2 = disp( 123 )
list3 = disp( 'a' )

print ( list1 )
print ( list2 )
print ( list3 )
```

The output will be

```
[ 10 ]
[ 123 ]
[ 'a' ]
```

You can copy lists like this

```
list = Original.copy() # now those will be fundamentally different lists but same values
```

Or like this

```
list = [i for i in Original]
```